# Why I get optional value if I didn't mark it as optional

Tags: swift, swift3

I am rookie in swift and just learning.

Simple question why I get `optional` output in such sample

```
var dict = ["name" : "Alex", "secondName" : "Muren"]

let name = dict["name"]

print("\(name)")
```

Here output

```
Optional("Alex")
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I expect to get `Alex` not `Optional("Alex")`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just try with add  "!" mark after variable name Like: print("\(name!)")

Comment: @MitsMistri ok, but question was why? Ok now I understood

Comment: When you add "!" mark means you are taking guarantee of that object which holds the value.

Comment: @MitsMistri I know, question was , why I need to unwrap this value if I didn't set it as optional.

Comment: Yes you are right you didn't set value to optional but your dict["name"] return value as optional and you can see that put your cursor at end of dict["name"] and hit escape you will see like "String?".